# Can we do multivariate time series analysis using holt-winter ( Exponential smoothing) method?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, statsmodels

Just like we have a method like **ARIMAX** and **SARIMAX** where we can provide exog and endog variable for perfroming multivariate analysis. I was hoping is there a way, we can achieve same using ETS as well. Please let me know in case any has worked on this.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential smoothing is usually defined on univariate data with no exogenous variables (see e.g. [this book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/expsmooth.html)).

However, Rob Hyndman discusses different approaches of including exogenous variables in this [blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ets-regressors/) and gives some more references.

Comment: Thanks @mloning for pointing it out though it didn't solve my problem

Comment: @yogeshagrawal what is the problem you're trying to solve? Please update the question if necessary.